# Block automated requests without captcha

Tags: web-applications

I'm building an application that needs to count polling votes. As cookies, referrers and IP blocks all have big downsides, and we don't want to use captcha, I'm wondering what options (if any) we would have left to block automated votes.

I know we can't ever fully block them all, but I'm looking for ways to limit the impact, raise the barrier for the abusers.